# Coloring plot bar in python based on 2d array values and dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to learn Data Visualization and the city I live in actually uploaded some opendata on the city council tokens of presence.
I would like to display a bar for each council member, color it based on party membership and publish it.
I have a file with -in each row- "Name", "Party", "Total tokens received in €".
I divided each column in a different variable, then tried to

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv

with open('Book1.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
     readCSV  = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    names = []
    parties = []
   tots = []
   for row in readCSV:
       name = row[0]
       party = row[1]
       tot = row[2]

       names.append(name)
       parties.append(party)
       tots.append(tot)

tots = list(map(int,tots))
np_names = np.array(names)
np_parties = np.array(parties)
np_tots = np.array(tots)


 N = len(np_tots)
 x = range(N)
 width = 1/1.5

 col = {
    'PD' : 'red',
    'PDL' : 'blue',
    'Democrazia e Solidarieta' : 'pink',
    'UDC' : 'white',
    'Gruppo Misto' : 'gray',
    'Insieme per Pavia' : 'yellow',
    'Rinnovare Pavia' : 'green',
    }

 np_fin = np.column_stack((np_tots,np_parties))
 print(np_fin)
 plt.bar(x, np_fin[:,0], width, color= col.get(np_fin[:,0])
 plt.show()
```

I both lose the ints as they are converted back into strings in the new 2d array, and can't access the color-coded dictionary.

EDIT: Sample .csv

```
FRANCESCO,PD,0  
BRUNO,PDL,185   
MATTEO,Lega Nord,463
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your csv file?

Comment: Sure, let me edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seemed to be overcomplicating things a bit (in Python, the simpler your code is, the better).

Firstly, you don't need to convert your lists to arrays. Secondly, setting white as a colour for a bar means that nothing will show up. I have renamed the colour for UDC to purple.

The csv file example contained "Lega Nord" which didn't appear in the dictionary `col`. I also increased one of the values from 0 to 50 so we can see the actual bar. Therefore the csv file I am using looks like:

```
FRANCESCO,PD,50
BRUNO,PDL,185
MATTEO,UDC,463
```

For the colours of the bars, you need to create a list of colours that can be passed to `plt.bar`. You can access the value (colour in your case) of a dictionary by doing `col[key]` where `key` will be the contents of the list `parties`. Therefore we will need a loop, or a list comprehension as I have used in the example below.

You then need to simply plot the bars using `plt.bar(x, tots, color=cols)`. In order to label the x-axis, you need to plot only the ticks where the bars are, and then add the labels where those ticks are. This can be done using `plt.xticks(x, names)`.

Your code becomes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

col = {
    'PD' : 'red',
    'PDL' : 'blue',
    'Democrazia e Solidarieta' : 'pink',
    'UDC' : 'purple',
    'Gruppo Misto' : 'gray',
    'Insieme per Pavia' : 'yellow',
    'Rinnovare Pavia' : 'green',
    }

with open('Book1.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    readCSV  = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    names = []
    parties = []
    tots = []
    for row in readCSV:
        names.append(row[0])
        parties.append(row[1])
        tots.append(row[2]) 

N = len(tots)
x = range(N)

# create a list of colours from the dictionary if it appears in the list parties
cols = [col[key] for key in parties]  

plt.bar(x, tots, color=cols)
plt.xticks(x, names)   # set the x ticks at the position of the bars and set the label

plt.show()
```

Which produces the following figure:

[image]